ICML2025 Template: Spacing of Multiple Authors
I'm working on the ICLR 2025 template. It can be directly obtained at here. The problem is when multiple authors (say 4) are there and their spacing is large enough to force a newline for two authors, it creates an unequal spacing. See the following demo:

This is what I changed in the demo (which in this case I don't feel is necessary to include an MWE):
\author{Some People\\
Some Very Long School Name\\
\And
Some People\\
Some Very Long School Name\\
\And
Some People\\
Some Very Long School Name\\
\And
Some People\\
Some Very Long School Name
}

I think the problem is the definition of \And in iclr2025_conference.sty:
% Title (includes both anonimized and non-anonimized versions)
\def\@maketitle{\vbox{\hsize\textwidth
%\linewidth\hsize \vskip 0.1in \toptitlebar \centering
{\LARGE\sc \@title\par}
%\bottomtitlebar % \vskip 0.1in %  minus
\ificlrfinal
    \lhead{Published as a conference paper at ICLR 2025}
    \def\And{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[0]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[4]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\@author\end{tabular}%
\else
       \lhead{Under review as a conference paper at ICLR 2025}
   \def\And{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[0]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[4]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}Anonymous authors\\Paper under double-blind review\end{tabular}%
\fi
\vskip 0.3in minus 0.1in}}

I can't quite figure out how to fix it, but at least this should be the root cause, which is at least somewhere to start...
Any help is welcome.
